# Strange behaviour when inserting date from PHP into database

Tags: php, mysql, date

In "form.php"

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="process.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="dat" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In "process.php":

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['dat'];

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456")
            or die("can't connect");
    mysql_select_db("st")
        or die("can't selectdb");

    $query = "INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES ( " . $_POST['dat']. "  ) ";


    $result = mysql_query($query)
        or die(mysql_error());

    $mysql_close();

?>
```

This give me 0000-00-00 in the database, in the field name "time" of type "DATE".
If using this:

```
$time = explode("-", $_POST['dat']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES ( " .  date("m-d-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, $time[1], $time[2], $time[0])). "  ) ";
```

-> doesn't work either

EDIT:
I've changed from "m-d-Y" to "Y-m-d" for appropriate semantic, but it still doesn't work

However, if I change the code like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES ('1991-10-05') ";
```

it works.

Can anyone explain this for me?

Comment: `date("m-d-Y") != date("Y-m-d")`. How are you formatting `dat`?

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES ( " . $_POST['dat']. "  ) ";` be careful to avoid code like this, that is just the call for SQL injections.

Comment: Please, try to use PDO and prepared statements. It's not more difficult and you'll spend very little amount of time to learn it.

Comment: @silentbag: See here for quick overview: http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/php-security (point 3, but you'll want to read others too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither if your two PHP examples have the date being quoted. They'll generate queries that look like:

```
INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES (2009-01-02);
```

which will be parsed down to

```
INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES (2006)
```

2009-01-02 is a numeric literal with two subtractions, NOT a date. To get get MySQL to treat this as a date value, it MUST be quoted:

```
INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES ('2009-01-02');
                               ^----------^--- quotes MUST be present
```

So your PHP should look like:

```
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dat']);

$query = "INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES ('$dat');";
```

Comment: $newdate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dat']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES ( $newdate  ) "; and it's still 0000-00-00

Answer (score 2):

You want `date("Y-m-d"` not `date("m-d-Y"`

[See here for explanation of what date/time formats MySQL accepts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

Also you need quotes around date if you're using this format, because without them, MySQL thinks you're inserting a nymber: `1991-10-05 = 1976`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES ('" .  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $time[1], $time[2], $time[0])). "'  ) ";
```

Or alternatively shorter format and without quotes

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES (" .  date("Ymd", mktime(0, 0, 0, $time[1], $time[2], $time[0])). "  ) ";
```

and personally I'd do:

```
$ts = strtotime($_POST['dat']);
if($ts != 0) {
  $date = date('Ymd',$ts);    
  $query = "INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES ($date) ";
} else {
// invalid date format
}
```

And just like others said in comments: never put `$_POST` (or `$_GET` or any untrusted data) directly in your queries. Always escape/sanitize data first.

Comment: I've changed it to Y-m-d as you said. but still 0000-00-00

Comment: What's in $_POST['dat'] then?

Comment: if I echo $_POST['dat'] it's exactly what I want. ex:2009-01-02

Answer (score 1):

The dates are stored as Y-m-d

So your code should do :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sts (time) VALUES ( " .  date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $time[1], $time[2], $time[0])). "  ) ";
```